# How to open a web page from QlikView?

Tags: ajax, html, qlikview

I am starting to use QlikView.

I need to open a web site from QlikView script, for instance something like

```
call ("wwww.mywebsite.com").
```

Is possible to call a website from QlikView Script?

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking to launch a web page from a dashboard page component?  If so you can use a text object with an "Open URL" action. and specify the url (or an expression that returns a url)

If you need to use a web site as a datasource (ie a web service) then you can use the Web file wizard to construct the proper connection to the web service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have two options. You can either use the 'Web Files' wizard, or for more complicated web service calls you can use a macro and call it in your script.

Check out the following site:
http://blog.qvapps.com/2010/09/20/using-qlikview-with-web-services/